# Can't get Parse.initialize(this, "my app id", "my client id") work

Tags: android, parse-platform

So this is my App.java:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viMzf.jpg)

Then I add **android:name=".App"** in AndroidManifest.xml.

Also I've already add dependencies in my build.gradle.

When I try to run the application, it says this line has error:
**Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.app_id), getString(R.string.client_id));**

The error is thrown out in this way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiAIf.jpg)

Can someone give me some thoughts on what could be a possible reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message mentions the bolts dependency.

Your build.gradle should contain the following:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

If this is already the case it's perhaps your libraries. Have you included the SDK within the project?

Failing this there could be an issue with your strings, if you hardcode the app id and client id, does the problem persist

Comment: yeah I think that's the problem. Thanks a lot!